# Image derivatives removed by some process, only regenerated when switching to maintenance mode, then removed again

Tags: 7, files, maintenance-mode

While moving a bunch of legacy D7 sites to a new server, I bumped on the following problem with one site only. This is certainly NOT the classical permissions issue on files directory.

### Bug description

The images derivatives are removed by some process. Accessing the website **in maintenance mode regenerates all the image derivatives**, but **as soon as I disable maintenance mode** and visit a couple of pages, either with admin role or not, **the whole styles directory is flushed**, leaving `sites/default/files/styles` totally empty (!) and no images are regenerated anymore.

This behaves only on one site, other D7 or D8 sites are fine on the same server.

**In maintenance mode, set permissions properly, then list styles**

```
ls -ld sites/default/files/styles/*/
drwxrws--- 3 kojo www-data 4096 Jul  2  2016 sites/default/files/styles/gallery/
drwxrws--- 3 kojo www-data 4096 Dec  1 11:15 sites/default/files/styles/medium/
drwxrws--- 3 kojo www-data 4096 Dec  1 11:13 sites/default/files/styles/product/
#... and so on
```

**List again styles after leaving maintenance mode**

```
ls -ld sites/default/files/styles/*/
drwxrws--- 3 kojo www-data 4096 Jul  2  2016 sites/default/files/styles/gallery/
```

Only that gallery directory was not impacted ; it is indeed not a referenced style in UI, and while I don't remember why it is there *_ hum hum old projects :-( _* better ignore it for now. All the styles directories were completely removed.

**List after returning to maintenance mode**

```
ls -ld sites/default/files/styles/*/
drwxrws--- 3 www-data www-data 4096 Jul  2  2016 sites/default/files/styles/gallery/
drwxr-sr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Dec  1 11:15 sites/default/files/styles/medium/
drwxr-sr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Dec  1 11:13 sites/default/files/styles/product/
#... and so on
```

The whole tree was recreated, with different perms.

### Files directory permissions

I did set the same permissions as in any of my D7 sites :

```
cd /path_to_drupal_installation
chown -R kojo:www-data .
find . -type d -exec chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o= '{}' \; # 750 on directories by default
find . -type f -exec chmod u=rw,g=r,o= '{}' \; # 640 on files (except settings.php 440)
find sites/default/files -type d -exec chmod u=rwx,g=rwx,o= '{}' \; #770 for files dir
```

I then tried a more permissive way with 775 permissions, just to make sure. No luck.

### What else I tried to debug

1. `drush rq` , nginx error log, the server website log,  watchdog... return no errors.
2. `drush image-flush --all` flushes styles when there are some, but does not regenerate on the fly as described in doc.
3. Visiting each of the styles in `/admin/config/media/image-styles`, be in maintenance mode or not, recreates the directory tree and the "balloons examples images".
4. In the evening, I installed [ImageInfo Cache](https://www.drupal.org/project/imageinfo_cache) and performed a bulk regeneration with `drush image-generate all all`. This worked, and four hours later the styles were still there, but in the morning they had been removed! No CRON task was run during that night !
5. Switching from **PHP** 7.3 to 7.1 or 7.2 has no impact.
6. Forcing **Varnish** to fetch backend does not change behavior.
7. I did set settings.php, vhost of this site to be as strictly similar as possible to the other websites on that server.

### Environment

For all the moved websites, core is 7.75 and all the modules are up to date.

I'm running them on Debian 9 + NGINX + PHP 7.3. NGINX as proxy for SSL requests, forwarding them to Varnish which upon cache logic, serves cached pages or fetch NGINX back.

By the way I can't reproduce the issue on localhost in a DDEV container whichever PHP version so this might be a prod env problem ?

### Summary

- the D7 websites with same core work fine in that environment, with same permissions, settings, vhost
- I can't reproduce the bug in localhost DDEV container (so this should not be related to the theme or some updated module of this specific site ?)
- permissions are set correctly and giving permissive one has no effect
- the system is able to create the default images styles examples (balloons...)
- switching from HTTPS to HTTP has no effect
- changing PHP version has no effect

### Questions

Am I missing or misunderstanding a point ?

The key to understand what succeeds is probably **this behavior whenever toggling maintenance mode on/off**. What at the core level is succeeding then ? And what is in charge of flushing styles and when ?

Any tip or analysis is welcome to help me solving this weird issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you put the site in maintenance mode (drush or UI)? There might be a hook_form_alter performing some code (giving you the trace), as it's not usual that image dervatives get deleted/regenerated when switching the maintenance mode and in "other" cases like you described ...

Comment: I did put the site in maintenance mode via UI for these tests. What kind of hook_form_alter are you thinking about ? You mean some code I would not be aware of ? I built this legacy website myself and till last week, before updates and move, it was working fine. Thanks @rémy

Comment: Have you already tried to reproduce this locally without Varnish?

Comment: Yes, and I also tried with a rule in vcl fetching backend for all requests. Locally, I can't reproduce. And passing through Varnish does not remove the bug. By the way, I don't see how Varnish could be responsible of removing the entire styles directory ? Thanks @leymannx !

Comment: What updates ? Try to rollback, and do them one by one, toggle maintenance mode, and see if you find the causing module ..